# Why doesn't Microsoft Outlook respect list styles when sending HTML emails?

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have the following code and for the life of me I can't get it to work in Microsoft Outlook.

```
<ul style="margin-left: 50px; line-height: 50px; list-style: none;">
    <li style="font-size: 1.5em; list-style: none;">[UniqueCode]</li>
</ul>
```

Is there another way to achieve the same result? I am attempting to send a HTML email to a group of people.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Have a look at [Campaign Monitor's guide](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) to CSS support in HTML emails.

`list-style-image`, `list-style-position` and `list-style-type` are not supported in Outlook 2007 or Outlook 2010.

Using table cells for layout is standard practice in HTML email builds because CSS support in Outlook is really bad.

Try using table cells with exact widths specified for the layout of your list, and have each item in a new row or separated by `<br>s`.

Comment: Thanks. I did find out that Outlook 2007 and 2010 do not support them and had to rewrite the entire HTML email in tables. What a bummer!

Comment: "Using table cells for layout is standard practice in html email builds because css support in Outlook is really bad."
I knew this already but it's still depressing to read. +1 for the workarounds

Comment: The reference is a gold link! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tried giving the `<ul>` a text color that matched the background and then used a `<span>` assigning the correct color for the text. For instance, if you were using a `#c4c4c4` background with black text.

```
<ul style="list-style: none;color:#c4c4c4;">
  <li><span style="color:#000000;">Something</span></li>
</ul>
```

The bullets, if displayed, blend in with the background, but the text will show.